# laravel store files and access them

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I store files using this code:

```
 $files = $request->file('files');
    if($request->hasFile('files'))
    {
        foreach($files as $file)
        {
            $file->store('files'));
        }
    }
```

The files in this example are saved under `storage/app/files/`, which is fine since they are thus not publicly accessible (which they are neither supposed to). However, if I want to provide my users with a download option of these files, how will I access them? I thought of PHP reading the file and 'render' it to the user. However, I'm new to laravel and a bit lost at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-downloads

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. Now what about an image file which should be displayed within my webpage (like a profile picture, for example)?

Comment: Is that a case of file response (covered in the docs one tab below your answer), @apokryfos?

Comment: Yes that is what you'd use for "inline" file responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 3 main ways to send files as responses:

**File download** (uses content disposition: attachment)

```
return response()->download(storage_path("app/files/filename.ext")); //Where filename.ext is the file you want to send
```

**Inline file** (uses content disposition: inline)

```
return response()->file(storage_path("app/files/filename.ext"));
```

There's also falling back to [Symfony's streamed response](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.html) for very large files.

Comment: This looks good. However, how could I now (using 'inline file') render my image to HTML? Usually, I set the image source via HTML attribute: `<img src=...>`

Comment: @John you can set the `src=/route/that/sends/the/file/response/` (or even better (`src="{{url('route/that/sends/the/file/response')}}"`)

Comment: All right, this is what I had in my mind but wasn't exactly sure whether there's an easier way in laravel.